# Angular doesn't parse curly brackets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I don't get Angular to work. The thing that happens is dat I see literally `{{ foobar }}` on the screen.

Here are my files:

Index.cshtml of /App/Index:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="tournament">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Angular/routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Toernooien</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("tournament", []);
```

routes.js:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', { templateUrl: '/Home/Index', controller: 'HomeController' });
});
```

HomeController.js:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foobar = 'barFoo';
});
```

Index.cshtml of /Home/Index

```
<script src="~/Angular/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<div>
      Home/index
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="foo" />
    {{ foobar }}
</div>
```

Comment: From the code you've shared it looks like you didn't include `HomeController.js` where the `HomeController` is defined

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code. I've added a script tag @ the index.cshtml of Home/Index

Comment: @DarinDimitrov No, I want my controllers in separate files.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `Index.cshtml` files?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I use ASP.NET MVC. Both index.cshtml files are in a different folder.

Comment: How is /home/index.cshtml being loaded? Is it returned as a view, or being loaded as a partial in response to an ajax call?

Comment: @Jason I have an action method which just returns view: `return View()` in the action method `public ActionResult Index()` of HomeController.

Comment: Maybe try defining the app/routes/controller in a single js file and then pull them into seperate files one by one to find out where its going wrong.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your suggestions. I finally solved my issue. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me. I finally figured it out. The problem was in my MVC controller.

This is what I had originally:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And this is the solution:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Now, everything is working like it should be.